# WAMP shows error 'MSVCR100.dll' is missing when install on my computer

Tags: wamp, wampserver, msvcr100.dll

When I install WAMP, that show following alert,

The program can't start because MSVCR.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

gave OK, then installed the wamp. When I start, WAMP logo is always 'yellow' color only. That's not return to 'green'. What is MSVCR100.dll file? Where i can download it? and where i can paste that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSVCR100.dll is a C++ driver that is needed for WAMP.  You can download it from  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3067

Comment: Its actually a C/C++ runtime library required to run the Apache code compiled with VS2012(VC11)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't add a comment, but... the OP's accepted answer does not point to a C++ driver download as of 7/28/2015. It is a PDF download for some info on making phone calls or the like. (NOT C++)